# PHP - display POSTed image

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I'm sending a .jpeg to the below server using an HTML form

How do I get PHP to successfully display the image once the server receives it?

```
<?php 
       if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
          {
              echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
          }
        else
          {
              echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
              echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
              echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
              echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
          }

        $img = $_FILES["file"];

        echo $img;

?>
```

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` is an array with data about the upload. It does NOT contain the actual image.

Comment: @MarcB How do I get the actual image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                    $target_path.'/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

So that you move the temporary file and then you can show it with

```
 print '<img src="http://yoursite.com/url_of_target_path/'.
          $_FILES["file"]["name"].'"/>
```

Beware not to use the exact code I provided, before sanitizing uploaded data.

Comment: So my I'm setting <img src=$server_path/$src/>  where $server_path =  "http://localhost/photoServerProject/photoServer.php";
and $src = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; But I keep getting a server error

Comment: This is horribly DANGEROUS code, allowing a user to scribble a file of their choosing ANYWHERE on the server.

Comment: Relax, I'm running a local server, which only I have access to

Comment: @MarcB That's why I clearly mention "Beware not to use the exact code I provided".

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the content header to the corresponding image format before you `echo $img`

for example if the uploaded image is `jpg` it should be

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $img;
```

also make sure that you are not `echo`ing text data along with it.